# Apple review process: Penalty for updating an app before it has been reviewed

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have submitted an app to the app store about a week ago. As far as I can tell, it wasn't reviewed yet.

Today my team discovered a bug in the app we've sent. It's not critical, but I would be very happy to have it in the store without it.

**If I submit a fixed app before my app has been previewed, will my app be moved to the back of the review queue?**

I found no direct reference to this question in the [app store review process manual](https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/app-review/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To submit a new build of an app for review, the current build must be removed from review. This sets the status to Developer Rejected, which is equivalent to a review rejection. Once you have changed the build, you can submit it for review once again, which will put it at the back of the queue.

> Removing a build removes your app version from Apple’s review queue and changes its status to Developer Rejected. When you resubmit your app, the review process starts over from the beginning.

<sup>Source: [iTunes Connect Developer Guide - Viewing and Changing Your App’s Status and Availability - Removing a Build from Review](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW34)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Could you kindly provide a reference link, please?

Comment: @Adam Added a quote from the documentation